# Order months correctly in plot - Python pandas matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I saw on this forum different methods of this problem solution, but i can't implement this into my code. I need to made to x axis will be in correcting order so you know: january, february, march, april, may etc. I changed numbers (because i receive big data frame with 319000 rows, and in DF column 'Month' looks like Month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]) of column 'Month' to name of months, by import calendar and use "apply(lambda x:...", how can you see.  I know this maybe a very newbie question, but I will appreciate if someone can help me.

Code:

```
wykres = MojaBaza['Month'].astype(int).apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x]).value_counts().sort_values(ascending=True).plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8,8),
title="Amount of the crimes in Boston during the months in years 2015-2018 ")

    wykres.set_xticklabels(wykres.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image: img]

Comment: presumably `.sort_values(ascending=True)` is your problem here - I would assume that is sorting the dataframe by the counts in the column you are plotting (i.e. the y axis - which is why the bar heights are ascending from left to right). Try removing that, they should be in the original order

Comment: If I remove `.sort_values(ascending=True)`, then I have ascending right to left, so almost this same. I need to have january first on left, and december last on right. Thank you for fast response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the data, so I created sample data and created the code. I created a list of month names, converted the aggregate values from the calendar into a primary data frame, and then updated the index with the month name list.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import calendar

date_rng = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2019-01-01', freq='1D')
val = np.random.randint(5,50,(1462,))

MojaBaza = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(date_rng), 'value':val})

MojaBaza['Month'] = MojaBaza['date'].dt.month
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
temp = MojaBaza['Month'].astype(int).apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x]).value_counts().reset_index()
temp.set_index('index', inplace=True)
temp = temp.reindex(index=months)
wykres = temp.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8,8), title="Amount of the crimes in Boston during the months in years 2015-2018 ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I implement this to my code and it's working :)